# How to limit the amount of times it adds to an array / csv file - text based spotify

Tags: python, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, random

I've been making a text-based spotify program in python. One of my friends has this as a task in school and he interested me! One of the tasks is to generate random playlists. The one i'm stuck on is generating a random playlist by genre.

5a. Generate a random playlist by genre with at least 5 songs from that genre.

I have a csv file that holds about 20 songs, it has the following information:
Song name | Artist | Genre | Track length

This is my current code so far:

```
import random
import csv

genre_list = ["Pop","Rock","Rap"]
playlist = []

random_genre = random.choice(genre_list)

data = list(csv.reader(open("song.csv")))
name = input("Enter name for the playlist: ")

for row in range(len(data)):
    if random_genre == data[row][2]:
        playlist.append(data[row])

print(playlist)
newfile = open(name + ".csv","w")
for i in range(len(playlist)):
    newfile.write(str(playlist[i][0]+","+playlist[i][1]+","+playlist[i]
[2]+","+playlist[i][3]))
    newfile.write(str("\n"))
newfile.close()
print("done! ")
```

Only problem I have is that it adds **every** song from that genre. How do I make it so it limits to 5 songs?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply check for the length of the playlist

```
for row in range(len(data)):
    if random_genre == data[row][2] and len(playlist) < 5:
        playlist.append(data[row])
```

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't noticed this, thanks - life saver!

Comment: welcome, mark it as an answer if it has solved your problem this will help others as well

Answer (score 0):

```
genre_songs = [song for song in data if song[2] == random_genre]
playlist = random.sample(genre_songs,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to count how many songs get put into the `playlist`, which is easy because at any given time its length is `len(playlist)`.

You're also not taking much advantage of the `csv` module, nor how Python will automatically close files if you use the `with` statement when opening them.

Here's essentially a rewrite of your code show how to do all these things:

```
import random
import csv

genre_list = "Pop","Rock","Rap"
random_genre = random.choice(genre_list)

name = input("Enter name for the playlist: ")
MAX_SONGS = 5

playlist = []
with open("song.csv", "r", newline="") as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        if row[2] == random_genre:
            playlist.append(row)
            if len(playlist) >= MAX_SONGS:
                break

print(playlist)

newfilename = name + ".csv"
with open(newfilename, "w", newline="") as newfile:
    writer = csv.writer(newfile)
    writer.writerows(playlist)

print("done!")
```